# Calling a method inside an anonymous eventhandler function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, eventhandler

I'm trying to write a browser plugin. But my JS is a bit rusted. Could somebody explain why I can not call the "presentTheAnswer" method? I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: presentTheAnswer is not defined
at getData (<anonymous>:4:13)
at <anonymous>:5:11
```

Here is the Code

```
document.getElementById("mightyButton").addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("Popup DOM fully loaded and parsed");

    function getData() {
        var data = 42;

        presentTheAnswer(data);
    }


    function presentTheAnswer(data){

        //do something
    }

    //We have permission to access the activeTab, so we can call chrome.tabs.executeScript:
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: '(' + getData + ')();' //argument here is a string but function.toString() returns function's code
    }, null);           
});
```

I already tried if the order matters (like in C?). But this didn't change anything

Comment: How is `getData()` actually called?  That's not shown in your example code.

Comment: Assuming you are calling getData, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ksoa40yb/1/

Comment: yeah, function order shouldn't matter because of hoisting within the scope of your "fat arrow" anonymous function.

Comment: I added the missing link. getData is called from the very bottom.

Comment: You don't actually call `getData`, you just copy its body and pass it to `chrome.tabs.executeScript` which parses a new function with that same code but in a completely different context. `presentTheAnswer` doesn't exist in this context because it's not part of the code you passed to `chrome.tabs.executeScript`

Comment: Hi @Lennholm Ok. So how should I arrange these methods so that I can structure the code in a more readable way (not putting all in one huge function)